# SSL Binding Not Working on Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function app that has been working completely fine over the past few weeks but the SSL binding on the Custom domain has stopped working. The SSL is not expired or anything like that.

The error response is:

```
Not found because of proxy error: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: api.mydomain.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.azurewebsites.net, DNS:*.scm.azurewebsites.net, DNS:*.azure-mobile.net, DNS:*.scm.azure-mobile.net”
```

The portal shows the binding correctly under the Azure Functions settings. Also this is an Azure Function on consumption plan.

I have initialized a support but no luck resolving this.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can you let us know the name of your functionapp as per instructions here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: It is an azure function app and here is the log info to find it:
2017-10-25T18:07:42.916 Function started (Id=f974616c-f889-4101-865c-f61e94796e46)

Comment: I think I am just going to have to remove it as a consumption plan and readd it as an app service

Answer (score 2):

After lots of work with the support team and some of the internal team members I was able to track down the issue. The issue all turned out to be related to it being a **Consumption Plan**. If you are using the consumption plan, the custom domains with SSL **do not work at this time.**

Apparently this is coming in the future.

Comment: It is possible to enable SSL for functionapps in Consumption Plan. There is currently a bug where SSL cannot be enabled for a functionapp if it is in the same resource group and region where you already have a regular webapp with IP SSL enabled. But if you create a functionapp in a separate resource group then it should be possible to enable SNI SSL for it.

Comment: Wow that is a bad bug

Comment: @RuslanY any eta of when that bug will be fixed ?

Comment: The fix will be deployed in production in middle of November.

Comment: @RuslanY is it fixed now?

Comment: I haven't seen an official word on it.

Comment: @Jonathan - it should be fixed in production. Do you still see it not working?

Comment: I had to abandon this for now but may revisit it in the future

Comment: @RuslanY I'm trying the same thing unsuccessfully. I can't find any official guidance on this subject yet, so anything you can point us to would be much appreciated! This link (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) suggests that SNI SSL is available for Consumption Plan-hosted Functions.